# org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 18 of [] in my mobile

Tags: android, json

i checked almost all solution on this error on stackoverflow but i can't find right solution
i am fetching data from third party service it returns JSON Array 
it gives org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 18 of [JsonArray] in my mobile phone but it gives desired result in emulator my mobile have android 8.1
and my emulator have android 12

my code

```
val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
val jsonArrayobj=JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,finalurl,null,{ response->

   //process on data

},{
       Log.d("vollyError",it.message.toString())
//     Toast.makeText(context, "Erroroccured",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
   })
queue.add(jsonArrayobj)
```

Comment: Can you share your JSON Array as well? @Ysp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now my app working fine I think there was an error in data which I got from api.